# Lower bound for $\pi(x)$

Tags: inequality, prime-numbers

Is there a way to show that
$$\frac{x}{\ln x} < \pi(x),$$
for sufficiently large $x$, using only elementary calculus? Apparently it is true for $x \geq 17$ (see this [article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807)). However, I am looking for a simpler proof.